# Jackrabbit Oak and integrate Solr

Tags: jackrabbit-oak

I'm new to Jackrabbit Oak, I'm trying to integrate with Solr remote server. I could not do it, I read the documentation, I have studied the source Jackrabbit 1.4.0 Oak without result. Someone has something that can illustrate me how. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Oak 1.4.x repository is setup correctly, creating a Solr index with the following structure should be enough to start seeing content being ingested into the remote Solr instance (e.g. placed at http://localhost:8983/solr/oak) configured with the config provided at [1]:

```
/oak:index/solrRemote
  - jcr:primaryType = "oak:QueryIndexDefinition"
  - type = "solr"
  - async = "async"
  + server
    - jcr:primaryType = "nt:unstructured"
    - solrServerType = "remote"
    - httpUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/oak"
```

[1] : https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/tree/trunk/oak-solr-core/src/main/resources/solr/oak